# Running java from VBA macro in Windows 7 bypassing System32 / SysWOW64 javaw.exe

Tags: java, vba, shell, windows-7, 32bit-64bit

Is there a way to bypass the 32-bit java version (maybe a different way to start a proccess in VBA to invoke the 64-bit version cmd, turn off the UAC or some other sort of tweek) that is being "forced" by the following VBA code (this is just an assumption, I am explaining the debugging process below):

```
handleDbl = Shell("javaw -cp theJar.jar com.java.SampleClass", vbNormalFocus)
```

The main point here is that I want to share my macro and avoid putting extra instructions on the recipient so I am trying to do everything on the code (I am using late binding on VBA code to avoid to setting References manually and that kind of stuff).

### Debugging Process

An error was thrown so I used the following line instead:

```
handleDbl = Shell("cmd /k java -cp theJar.jar com.java.SampleClass", vbNormalFocus)
```

And got the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version` so I checked the `java -version` and tried to find out which java was running with:

```
C:\>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\_anyJava.x.x.x_\bin\java.exe
```

I went to `System32` folder and there was no java there but I knew that [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector) happens from there to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` so I compared the previously extracted java version against `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\java.exe -version` and they matched.

After that I checked my Outlook version and turned out to be a 32-bit installation. That was a hint but it was mostly that and that big ***32** next to the cmd.exe in the Task Manager. I don't know if a 64-bit Outlook would make a difference or it would be the same because of the VBA implementation but that's how I concluded the Shell function from VBA is causing 32-bit java call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally there is a JAVA_HOME environment variable set. If so, then you can do something like this:

```
Dim JavaExe As String
JavaExe = """" & Environ("JAVA_HOME") & "\bin\java.exe"""
handleDbl = Shell("cmd /k " & JavaExe & " -cp theJar.jar com.java.SampleClass", vbNormalFocus)
```

If it isn't set, you'll have to find it by some searching, before compiling the command.

Answer (score 0):

[Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246362/sam)'s answer is great but I just felt uneasy about user going through more settings so I wrote some functions to check java's versions and notify the user if it is not there (would have to install java in that case anyway) so here is my code. It might contain some helpful stuff.

```vbs
Private Function IsJavaAvailable(ByVal displayMessage As Boolean, Optional ByVal isJavaMandatory As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim availability As Boolean
    Dim minJavaVersion As Integer
    minJavaVersion = 8

    'isJavaSetup is a global variable
    If (Not isJavaSetup) Then
        javawPathQuoted = GetMinimumJavaVersion(minJavaVersion)
        If StrComp(javawPathQuoted, "") <> 0 Then
            isJavaSetup = True
        End If
        SetGlobalVars
    End If

    If javawPathQuoted = Empty Then
        availability = False
    Else
        availability = True
    End If

    If (displayMessage) Then
        If (isJavaMandatory) Then
            If Not availability Then
                MsgBox "This functionality is NOT available without Java " & minJavaVersion & "." & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Please install Java " & minJavaVersion & " or higher.", vbCritical, _
                "Mimimum Version Required: Java " & minJavaVersion
            End If
        Else
            If Not availability Then
                MsgBox "Some features of this functionality were disabled." & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Please install Java " & minJavaVersion & " or higher.", vbExclamation, _
                "Mimimum Version Required: Java " & minJavaVersion
            End If

        End If
    End If

    IsJavaAvailable = availability

End Function

Private Function GetMinimumJavaVersion(ByVal javaMinimumMajorVersionInt As Integer) As String

    'Run a shell command, returning the output as a string
    Dim commandStr As String
    Dim javawPathVar As Variant
    Dim javaPathStr As Variant
    Dim javaVersionStr As String
    Dim javaMajorVersionInt As Integer

    Dim detectedJavaPaths As Collection
    Dim javaVersionElements As Collection
    Dim javaVersionOutput As Collection
    Dim detectedJavaVersions As Collection

    Dim suitableJavawPath As String

    'Check available javaw executables in the SO
    commandStr = "where javaw"
    Set detectedJavaPaths = GetCommandOutput(commandStr)
    Set detectedJavaVersions = New Collection

    For Each javawPathVar In detectedJavaPaths

        'Look for java.exe instead of javaw.exe by substituting it in path
        '  javaw.exe does NOT return version output like java.exe
        javaPathStr = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(javawPathVar), StrReverse("javaw.exe"), StrReverse("java.exe"), , 1))
        commandStr = """" & javaPathStr & """" & " -version"
        Set javaVersionOutput = GetCommandOutput(commandStr)
        javaVersionStr = javaVersionOutput.item(1)

        Debug.Print "Getting java version: ", commandStr
        Debug.Print "Version detected: "; javaVersionStr

        Set javaVersionElements = SplitOnDelimiter(javaVersionStr, " ")

        'Check that output is not an error or something else
        'java version "1.8.0_75"
        If javaVersionElements.Count > 2 Then
            If StrComp(javaVersionElements.item(1), "java", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                If StrComp(javaVersionElements.item(2), "version", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    detectedJavaVersions.Add javaVersionStr
                    'Remove quotes from "1.8.0_75", split on '.', get 2nd item (java major version) and cast it to Integer
                    javaMajorVersionInt = CInt(SplitOnDelimiter(SplitOnDelimiter(javaVersionElements.item(3), """").item(1), ".").item(2))
                    'JAR will only run in Java 8 or later
                    If (javaMajorVersionInt >= javaMinimumMajorVersionInt) Then
                        'Validate that "javaw.exe" exists since the validation was made with "java.exe"
                        Debug.Print "Verifying if javaw.exe exists: ", javawPathVar
                        If Len(Dir(javawPathVar)) > 0 Then
                            suitableJavawPath = javawPathVar
                            Debug.Print "A suitable javaw.exe version found: ", suitableJavawPath
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next javawPathVar

    GetMinimumJavaVersion = suitableJavawPath

End Function

Private Function GetCommandOutput(ByRef commandStr As String) As Collection

    'Run a shell command, returning the output as a string
    Dim shellObj As Object
    Set shellObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'run command
    Dim wshScriptExecObj As Object
    Dim stdOutObj As Object
    Dim stdErrObj As Object
    Set wshScriptExecObj = shellObj.Exec(commandStr)
    Set stdOutObj = wshScriptExecObj.StdOut
    Set stdErrObj = wshScriptExecObj.StdErr

    'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object
    Dim fullOutputCollection As Collection
    Set fullOutputCollection = New Collection

    Dim lineStr As String
    While Not stdOutObj.AtEndOfStream
        lineStr = stdOutObj.ReadLine
        If lineStr <> "" Then
            fullOutputCollection.Add lineStr
        End If
    Wend

    If fullOutputCollection.Count = 0 Then
        While Not stdErrObj.AtEndOfStream
            lineStr = stdErrObj.ReadLine
            If lineStr <> "" Then
                fullOutputCollection.Add lineStr
            End If
        Wend
    End If



    Set GetCommandOutput = fullOutputCollection

End Function
```